# How to consume an Ember-Data style API in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ember-data

I am attempting to consume a third party API Response which follows the structure below.

```
{
   'product': [{'id': 'foo', 'group': 'bar'},{'id': 'jim', 'group': 'bob'}],
   'group': [{'id': 'bar', 'kingdom':'baz'},{'id': 'cake', 'group': 'steak'}],
   'kingdom': [{'id': 'baz'},{'id':'apple'}],
}
```

I want to translate this into a nested data structure of the form

```
**Product** 
{
    id: 'foo',
    group: {
        id: 'bar',
        kingdom: {
            id: 'baz'
        }
    }

}
```

however it is important to note that in the scenario above product provides a pointer to group and subsequently group provides a pointer through id to kingdom. This could persist through many levels and as such i need a solution that is able to derive this information all from the original "base" list (in this case product). I do have the small mercy of each Key in the original data being unique to one type of data. eg. 'product' is always a Product

I am also hopeful that any solution found could avoid doing the transformation if the data is never asked for (be lazy) So for example if I never ask for product.group.kingdom.name in the template then no work is done to resolve the kingdom. Originally i attempted the following using services that returned observables for each layer

**For Example:**

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    group: Observable<Group>;
}
```

The idea with this was to use the Async pipe for each layer of data to resolve only when needed.

**As Shown Below**

`<span>{{((product | async).group | async).name}}</span>`

However, this did not resolve as i anticipated and from further research this format of nested Observable + subscription seems to be an anti-pattern.

Subsequently i removed nested observables accepting that the values would be calculated upfront and using RXJS pipe() operator alongside Map() operator i transformed the data into the format desired. Converting the API response initially into a map for faster key access.

**For Example**

```
createMaps(data) 
    let mapped_map = new Map();
    for (let key in data.data) {
        let values = data.data[key];
        mapped_map[key] = new Map();
        values.forEach((value) => {
            if (value.uuid) {
                mapped_map[key][value.uuid] = value
            } else if (value.id) {
                mapped_map[key][value.id] = value
            }
        })
    };
    return mapped_map;
}
```

The data was then looped over and assigned from the maped response. A new instance of the product model class was created to try and avoid referencing, however this was not working successfully and referencing was overriding the value of [product.group.kingdom] and causing the second line within the map function to fail on subsequent run throughs if the product mapped to the same kingdom. **(An adapter was used to create the new Product)**.

**Map Example**

```
data.map((product) => {
    let new_product = Product.adapt(product);
    new_product.group = mapped_map['group'][product.group]
    new_product.group.kingdom = mapped_map['kingdom'][product.group.kingdom]
}
```

**Adapter Example**

```
static adapt(product: any) Product {
    return new Product (
       item.id || undefined,
       item.group || undefined,
    )
}
```

Any advice on where i am going wrong (or possible design patterns for the following) would be greatly appreciated. Also if anyone has any suggestions as to how i can avoid referencing the product value used in the `map()` to access the maped_map key values would be fantastic. I have tried using lodash both _clone and _cloneDeep and neither worked successfully.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if further information would help.

Comment: If you want it to be "lazy" and not actually populate groups into product objects and kingdom into group objects, why not just create a getter function that you call to get the associated child object? Showing it would be something like `{{productA.getGroup().getKingdom().id}}`